# how to parse json array using retrofit android

Tags: java, android, json

```
{
  "name": "",
  "link": "",
  "menuId": "",
  "icon": null,
  "desc": null,
  "selected": false,
  "subMenus": [
    {
      "name": "Dashboard",
      "link": "/welcome",
      "menuId": "das",
      "icon": "fa fa-tachometer fa-2x",
      "desc": null,
      "selected": false,
      "subMenus": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Master",
      "link": "",
      "menuId": "emp",
      "icon": "fa fa-user-plus fa-2x",
      "desc": null,
      "selected": false,
      "subMenus": [
        {
          "name": "Roles",
          "link": "/myRoles",
          "menuId": "emp-usr-rol",
          "icon": null,
          "desc": null,
          "selected": false,
          "subMenus": [
            {
              "name": "Create Role",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emp-usr-rol-add",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            },
            {
              "name": "Delete Role",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emp-usr-rol-del",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            },
            {
              "name": "Edit Role",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emp-usr-rol-edt",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            },
            {
              "name": "List Role",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emp-usr-rol-lst",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "User",
          "link": "/users",
          "menuId": "emp-usr",
          "icon": null,
          "desc": null,
          "selected": false,
          "subMenus": [
            {
              "name": "Create User",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emp-usr-add",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            },
            {
              "name": "Delete User",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emp-usr-del",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            },
            {
              "name": "Edit User",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emp-usr-edt",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            },
            {
              "name": "List User",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emp-usr-lst",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Departments",
          "link": "/department",
          "menuId": "emp-mst-dpt",
          "icon": null,
          "desc": null,
          "selected": false,
          "subMenus": [
            {
              "name": "Create Department",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emp-mst-dpt-add",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            },
            {
              "name": "Delete Department",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emp-mst-dpt-del",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            },
            {
              "name": "Edit Department",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emp-mst-dpt-edt",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            },
            {
              "name": "List Department",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emp-mst-dpt-lst",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Salary Template",
          "link": "",
          "menuId": "emp-usr-rol",
          "icon": null,
          "desc": null,
          "selected": false,
          "subMenus": [
            {
              "name": "Create Salary Template",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emp-usr-rol-add",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            },
            {
              "name": "Delete Salary Template",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emp-usr-rol-del",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            },
            {
              "name": "Edit Salary Template",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emp-usr-rol-edt",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            },
            {
              "name": "List Salary Template",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emp-usr-rol-lst",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Job Schedular",
          "link": "",
          "menuId": "emp-usr-rol",
          "icon": null,
          "desc": null,
          "selected": false,
          "subMenus": [
            {
              "name": "Create Job Schedular",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emp-usr-rol-add",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            },
            {
              "name": "Delete Job Schedular",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emp-usr-rol-del",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            },
            {
              "name": "Edit Job Schedular",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emp-usr-rol-edt",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            },
            {
              "name": "List Job Schedular",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emp-usr-rol-lst",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Shift Management",
          "link": "",
          "menuId": "emp-usr-rol",
          "icon": null,
          "desc": null,
          "selected": false,
          "subMenus": [
            {
              "name": "Create Shift Management",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emp-usr-rol-add",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            },
            {
              "name": "Delete Shift Management",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emp-usr-rol-del",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            },
            {
              "name": "Edit Shift Management",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emp-usr-rol-edt",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            },
            {
              "name": "List Shift Management",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emp-usr-rol-lst",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Leave Management",
          "link": "/holidays",
          "menuId": "hrm",
          "icon": "fa fa-briefcase fa-2x",
          "desc": null,
          "selected": false,
          "subMenus": [
            {
              "name": "Holidays",
              "link": "/holidays",
              "menuId": "emp-mst-hdy",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": [
                {
                  "name": "Create Holiday",
                  "link": null,
                  "menuId": "emp-mst-hdy-add",
                  "icon": null,
                  "desc": null,
                  "selected": false,
                  "subMenus": []
                },
                {
                  "name": "Delete Holiday",
                  "link": null,
                  "menuId": "emp-mst-hdy-del",
                  "icon": null,
                  "desc": null,
                  "selected": false,
                  "subMenus": []
                },
                {
                  "name": "Edit Holiday",
                  "link": null,
                  "menuId": "emp-mst-hdy-edt",
                  "icon": null,
                  "desc": null,
                  "selected": false,
                  "subMenus": []
                },
                {
                  "name": "List Holiday",
                  "link": null,
                  "menuId": "emp-mst-hdy-lst",
                  "icon": null,
                  "desc": null,
                  "selected": false,
                  "subMenus": []
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "Leave Template",
              "link": "",
              "menuId": "emp-usr-rol",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": [
                {
                  "name": "Create Leave Template",
                  "link": null,
                  "menuId": "emp-usr-rol-add",
                  "icon": null,
                  "desc": null,
                  "selected": false,
                  "subMenus": []
                },
                {
                  "name": "Delete Leave Template",
                  "link": null,
                  "menuId": "emp-usr-rol-del",
                  "icon": null,
                  "desc": null,
                  "selected": false,
                  "subMenus": []
                },
                {
                  "name": "Edit Leave Template",
                  "link": null,
                  "menuId": "emp-usr-rol-edt",
                  "icon": null,
                  "desc": null,
                  "selected": false,
                  "subMenus": []
                },
                {
                  "name": "List Leave Template",
                  "link": null,
                  "menuId": "emp-usr-rol-lst",
                  "icon": null,
                  "desc": null,
                  "selected": false,
                  "subMenus": []
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Employee Management",
      "link": "",
      "menuId": "emng",
      "icon": "fa fa-user fa-2x",
      "desc": null,
      "selected": false,
      "subMenus": [
        {
          "name": "Employee",
          "link": "/users",
          "menuId": "emng-emp",
          "icon": null,
          "desc": null,
          "selected": false,
          "subMenus": [
            {
              "name": "Add Employees",
              "link": "/addEmployee",
              "menuId": "emng-emp-add",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            },
            {
              "name": "Delete Employees",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emng-emp-del",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            },
            {
              "name": "Edit Employees",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emng-emp-edt",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            },
            {
              "name": "List Employees",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emng-emp-lst",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Leave Approval",
          "link": "/leaveApproval",
          "menuId": "emng-lea",
          "icon": null,
          "desc": null,
          "selected": false,
          "subMenus": [
            {
              "name": "List Leave Approval",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emng-lea-lst",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            },
            {
              "name": "Edit Leave Approval",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emng-lea-edt",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Monthly Attendance",
          "link": "/monthlyAttendance",
          "menuId": "emng-mta",
          "icon": null,
          "desc": null,
          "selected": false,
          "subMenus": [
            {
              "name": "List Monthly Attendance",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emng-mta-lst",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Daily Attendance",
          "link": "/dailyAttendance",
          "menuId": "emng-dla",
          "icon": null,
          "desc": null,
          "selected": false,
          "subMenus": [
            {
              "name": "List Daily Attendance",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emng-dla-lst",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "In Out Register",
          "link": "/viewInOutRegister",
          "menuId": "emng-ior",
          "icon": null,
          "desc": null,
          "selected": false,
          "subMenus": [
            {
              "name": "List In Out Register",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emng-ior-lst",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Payroll Management",
      "link": "",
      "menuId": "pmng",
      "icon": "fa fa-paypal fa-2x",
      "desc": null,
      "selected": false,
      "subMenus": [
        {
          "name": "Salary Structure Template",
          "link": "/overtime",
          "menuId": "pmng-ot",
          "icon": null,
          "desc": null,
          "selected": false,
          "subMenus": [
            {
              "name": "Add Salary Structure Template",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "pmng-ot-add",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            },
            {
              "name": "List Salary Structure Template",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "pmng-ot-lst",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Association of template for Employee",
          "link": "",
          "menuId": "pmng-bnk",
          "icon": null,
          "desc": null,
          "selected": false,
          "subMenus": [
            {
              "name": " View template for Employee",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "pmng-bnk-add",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            },
            {
              "name": "delete template for Employee",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "pmng-bnk-del",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Salary Slip",
          "link": "",
          "menuId": "pmng-ot",
          "icon": null,
          "desc": null,
          "selected": false,
          "subMenus": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Employee Profile",
      "link": "",
      "menuId": "edsh",
      "icon": "fa fa-users fa-2x",
      "desc": null,
      "selected": false,
      "subMenus": [
        {
          "name": "Personal Details",
          "link": "",
          "menuId": "pmng-dtls",
          "icon": null,
          "desc": null,
          "selected": false,
          "subMenus": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Attendance",
          "link": "",
          "menuId": "edsh-emp",
          "icon": null,
          "desc": null,
          "selected": false,
          "subMenus": [
            {
              "name": "View Daily Attendance",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "edsh-emp-add",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            },
            {
              "name": "View Monthly Attendance",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "edsh-emp-lst",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Salary Pacakge Structure",
          "link": "",
          "menuId": "pmng-bnk",
          "icon": null,
          "desc": null,
          "selected": false,
          "subMenus": [
            {
              "name": "  View Salary Pacakge Structure ",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "edsh-ler-add",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            },
            {
              "name": "  Pay Slip ",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "edsh-ler-add",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Leave Application",
          "link": "/leaveRequest",
          "menuId": "edsh-ler",
          "icon": null,
          "desc": null,
          "selected": false,
          "subMenus": [
            {
              "name": "Apply Leave ",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "edsh-ler-add",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            },
            {
              "name": "View Leave Request",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "edsh-ler-lst",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            },
            {
              "name": "Edit Leave Request",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "edsh-ler-edt",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Shift Timings",
          "link": "",
          "menuId": "edsh-ior",
          "icon": null,
          "desc": null,
          "selected": false,
          "subMenus": [
            {
              "name": "View Shift Timings",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "edsh-ior-lst",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Holiday List",
          "link": "/holidayList",
          "menuId": "hld-lst",
          "icon": null,
          "desc": null,
          "selected": false,
          "subMenus": [
            {
              "name": "List Holiday",
              "link": null,
              "menuId": "emp-hld-lst",
              "icon": null,
              "desc": null,
              "selected": false,
              "subMenus": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Package",
      "link": "/pack",
      "menuId": "set-pkg",
      "icon": "fa fa-cogs fa-2x",
      "desc": null,
      "selected": true,
      "subMenus": [
        {
          "name": "Create package",
          "link": null,
          "menuId": "set-pkg-add",
          "icon": null,
          "desc": null,
          "selected": false,
          "subMenus": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Delete package",
          "link": null,
          "menuId": "set-pkg-del",
          "icon": null,
          "desc": null,
          "selected": false,
          "subMenus": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Edit package",
          "link": null,
          "menuId": "set-pkg-edt",
          "icon": null,
          "desc": null,
          "selected": false,
          "subMenus": []
        },
        {
          "name": "List package",
          "link": null,
          "menuId": "set-pkg-lst",
          "icon": null,
          "desc": null,
          "selected": false,
          "subMenus": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Organization",
      "link": "/org",
      "menuId": "set-org",
      "icon": "fa fa-cogs fa-2x",
      "desc": null,
      "selected": true,
      "subMenus": [
        {
          "name": "Create organization",
          "link": null,
          "menuId": "set-org-add",
          "icon": null,
          "desc": null,
          "selected": false,
          "subMenus": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Delete organization",
          "link": null,
          "menuId": "set-org-del",
          "icon": null,
          "desc": null,
          "selected": false,
          "subMenus": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Edit organization",
          "link": null,
          "menuId": "set-org-edt",
          "icon": null,
          "desc": null,
          "selected": false,
          "subMenus": []
        },
        {
          "name": "List organization",
          "link": null,
          "menuId": "set-org-lst",
          "icon": null,
          "desc": null,
          "selected": false,
          "subMenus": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: use this http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org site to convert json string to class in retrofit.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below link or something similar to first create a Java object class to hold the data
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

The use GsonConverterFactory with Retrofit to convert the object. Below link tells you how to add it
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-adding-customizing-the-gson-converter

Comment: can u create a pojo class for tat

Answer (score 0):

Create Pojo class and `implements`Serializable. Use this class to get a response.

try this,

```
class pojo implements Serializable{
     @SerializedName("name")
     private String name;

     public long getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setId(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: it wont work like tat.check with retrofit concepts and come back